# From records display only the one with highest price

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

I have a vanilla js app with express on the backend and mongoDB. Basically a restaurant builder, each customer can reserve a table with form. The inputs are name, select box with available table s and BID price. The bid means that the customer with highest bid for the table will win the table the other ones will lose it.

**How can I fetch only the customer with highest bid for the x table ?**

For example if I have 3 customers in below snippet booked in for tableID "2" how can I only get the one with the highest bid ?

Let's imagine a payload like this:

```
const bookings = [
  {
    customerName: 'Joe',
    bidValue: 178, // for example in $ - dollars
    tableID: 2
  },
  {
    customerName: 'Frank',
    bidValue: 212, // for example in $ - dollars
    tableID: 2
  },
  {
    customerName: 'Martin',
    bidValue: 123, // for example in $ - dollars
    tableID: 2
  },
  {
    customerName: 'John',
    bidValue: 15, // for example in $ - dollars
    tableID: 1
  },
  {
    customerName: 'Gino',
    bidValue: 87, // for example in $ - dollars
    tableID: 1
  },
  {
    customerName: 'Patrick',
    bidValue: 23, // for example in $ - dollars
    tableID: 3
  },
];
```

Comment: Is [this](https://mongoplayground.net/p/qBRZNHCf5BJ) what are you looking for? I can post a comment explaining the query if is correct.

Comment: Yes it is something that I'm looking for. It will basically give me a largest bid value customer. Just one more question here. How can I do it for each table. Let's imagine I have 10 tables @J.F.

Comment: To get this you need to use `$group`. Check [this](https://mongoplayground.net/p/-ieRZ2Et4gN) example. Also I'm going to post an answer explainint queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get only the highest value you need to use [`$sort`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sort/) and [`$limit`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/limit/) in this way:

- First `$match` to get the table which you can get the highest bid.
- Then `$sort` descending to get the highest value at first position
- And `$limit` to output only first value (i.e. the highest)

```
db.collection.aggregate(
{"$match": {"tableID": 2}},
{"$sort": {"bidValue": -1}},
{"$limit": 1})
```

Example [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/qBRZNHCf5BJ)

And, to get the highest value for each table you also need `$group` stage into the aggregation pipeline.

In this case, the query is a little bit different.

- First `$sort` to get the highest value on top and then
- `$group` by `tableId`.
- And use `$first` to get the max value because are sort, then, the first element will be the desired one.

```
{
  "$sort": {"bidValue": -1}
},
{
  "$group": {
    "_id": "$tableID",
    "customerName": {"$first": "$customerName"},
    "bidValue": {"$first": "$bidValue"}
  }
})
```

Example [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/-ieRZ2Et4gN)

Comment: Just want to ask. I got it all working. I added two new fields to the object wich has to determine if the customer is seated and if the customer is finished. So for example if I change isSeated flag to true for one of the customers the aggregate response still showing that the flag is false ... Why it's happening like this ??? cheers

Comment: Hi, can you share a playground with the problem? Where and how do you update the document?

Comment: Yes.Wil do and about updating so I'm loading all bookings through axios and then dynamically adding them into html. At every customer there's button called "seat" Which when clicked will update this customer isSeated flag in mongo to "true".

Comment: The thing here is whenever I update the field it's correctly updated even I can see changes in the mongo. But the above aggregate function is always showing this customer as isSeated: "false" ... can't understand why

Comment: The query shows the value for the highest `bidValue` in each `tableID`. Ensure you are setting `true` the seat with highest bind in a table. Check [this](https://mongoplayground.net/p/zq_ozvSrCz1) query. I've set `isSeated` as `true` for the highest prices and works. Check if it is the expected behaviour.

Comment: Found an issue. Sorry for panic. Enjoy the coffee man. @J.F.

Comment: I've had already this syntax that you send. But I had big mistake there. I was setting isFinished: { "$first": "$isSeated" }. So I was basically setting isFinished to whatever the isSeated was. But thanks anyway.. enjoy

Answer (score 1):

You should use the sort function (1 Ascending -1 descending).

```
db.bookings.find().sort( { "bidValue": 1 } )
```

- [More info on sorting](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/cursor.sort/)

Comment: not quite what I was looking for but thanks for effort anyway.